# How to find the source of a big memory consumption in a Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, out-of-memory, delphi-10-seattle, devart

I am experiencing a non normal memory consumption from my application written in Delphi 10 Seattle. It is a client server fat client type of application using SDAC's Devart as DB component.

I am not aware of specific tools, but I would like to know what causes the memory consumption.

What I observe is the following: as i launch a command the memory used by the exe grows a lot (up to 1 GB, in an app that used to use up to 200MB max) and sometimes this ends in an `out of memory` error. The stack trace of the out of memory error is of no use and seems random.

Could anyone please suggest a technique to study memory consumption?

I am currently studying memory leaks with FastMM4 and I managed to remove some, but there are just minor ones (`TStringlist` or some small `TBitmap`), nothing that justifies 1GB of memory consumption.

Is there a way to say "unit4.pas allocated 100MB of RAM" or any other similarly useful memory usage report?

Thanks a lot.

I feel stuck since I do not know the tools for this task.

Comment: Do you query database table columns with a BLOB type? If yes then figure out the largest datasets and see if avoiding them avoids memory consumption. [With PHP 7.1 I had a similar problem with MySQLi on TEXT columns](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71468#1487152385) ([older bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51386) and [Longtext max memory error using mysqli_query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47204427/4299358)).

Comment: Some information on sizes and # of current allocations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701671/how-to-monitor-or-visualize-memory-fragmentation-of-a-delphi-application/1701917

Comment: FastMM will only find leaks, not consumption (which I think you're aware so sorry to repeat).  I think @AmigoJack is on the right track, check what your db is doing.. my hunch is you are fetching a lot of records to the local machine, or your fetching records into local arrays etc.  Let us know.

Comment: This is a typical example of a question that can only be answered with speculative guesses, and is therefore not a good fit on SO. You should trace into your program starting from "as i launch a command" to look for the massive memory usage. We don't know what that command is or what it does.

Comment: Try that https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=895

Comment: @TomBrunberg Since I don't believe my answer to be a "speculative guess", I'd tend to disagree with you.

Comment: @AmigoJack I thought to be expert enough on this subject but once more it was because of a BLOB. You comment made me notice a field that was not  a blob in the past and now it is. Problem solved, if u answer I will accept it!

Comment: @TomBrunberg i disagree with you, in this case the comments inspired me, for the same reason this answer can inspire others in the future. I am so happy since I was really worried about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you query database table columns with a [BLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) type? If yes then figure out the largest datasets and see if avoiding them avoids memory consumption. [With PHP 7.1 I had a similar problem with MySQLi on TEXT columns](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71468#1487152385) ([older bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51386) and [Longtext max memory error using mysqli_query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47204427/4299358)).

Actually solving/preventing the memory consumption can surely be done - the [database abstraction layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer) surely knows an alternative method to query such columns in a way that works better for both sides: server and client. Feel free to edit this answer to include your actual code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. In fact I was inspired from your answer to check for blobs in the queries and I found a "forgotten" query in some remote part of the code that was really querying a blob field, by the way a field that used to be a text field and that in time become a blob field so the query kept reading from it. Anyway my problem is solved now, I will search for blobs manually in all queries. My app is a legacy app in which there are no layers, so queries are scattered bnut since the app has a value for the user my task is to maintain it and make it better and better day by day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a good memory/allocation profiler.

I don't know what features are typical or not in such a profiler because I only ever used one, but the one I use allows to get a report at anytime during a run that shows all the allocated memory and where in the application said memory was allocated.